# Clang fails to compile a c11 program, citing that "implicit declaration is illegal in c99"

Tags: c, clang, posix

I have written this trivial little program to demonstrate my problem (titled `hello.c`) (sidenote: I have noticed the memory leak in this program but it's just an example so it's not important):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    char * buf = NULL;
    size_t buflen = 0;

    ssize_t line_len;

    while ((line_len = getline(&buf, &buflen, stdin)) > 0) {
        buf[line_len - 1] = '\0';

        char * val = getenv(buf);

        if (val) {
            printf("setenv %s \"%s\"\n", buf, val);
        }
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "warning: %s not found\n", buf);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This compiles fine under Linux, using gcc and gnu make with the following makefile:

```
CFLAGS += -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wpedantic
CPPFLAGS := -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700

EXES := hello

all: $(EXES)

clean:
    rm -f $(EXES) *.o
```

However, under BSD, using clang and bmake, I cannot compile (using the exact same makefile and source file), because it says

```
hello.c:11:24: error: implicit declaration of function 'getline' is invalid in
  C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

The trouble is, as you can see, that I'm *not* compiling in c99 mode, but c11, and also, according to the man page defining `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to be 200809 or greater should enable getline, and elsewhere I am assured that defining `_XOPEN_SOURCE` to be 700 should achieve that.

Taking out the -W flags doesn't help.

So, what am I doing wrong? How can I get this to compile? I'm stumped.

Comment: Under OS X your code built and executed perfectly using your makefile and `make`. `gcc -v` included: `Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)`. So not a clang problem per se.

Comment: When it says "In C99" it means "In C99 or newer", at least in this case. You're not barking up quite the right tree :)

Comment: It appears to be the case that the cppflags aren't getting applied. I can compile it manually using `cc -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 ...` and so on. but running just `make` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @hobbs yes, sorry, I was aware of that, but I didn't mention it. That was my fault and I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have set `-std=c11 -Wpedantic`, which means that the normal defines are not available and POSIX function are not declared unless you explicitly set one of `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` or `_XOPEN_SOURCE`.  Add `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` (or even 800 on Linux) before the first `#include` and all will be well.

You have `CPPFLAGS = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` in the `makefile`; does `CPPFLAGS` actually show on the GCC command line?

I routinely compile on Mac OS X 10.10.1 with `-std=c11` and I have a header which sets `_XOPEN_SOURCE` to 700.  However, I can take your code and compile it verbatim with:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Werror -pedantic -c yourprog.c
```

and the only complaint is that neither `argc` nor `argv` is used (so the compilation does fail, but not because of `getline()`).

Note that `CPPFLAGS` is not necessarily recognized by BSD `make`.  There isn't a universal standard that requires `CPPFLAGS` to be recognized.

Comment: That's what the `CPPFLAGS :=` in the makefile is supposed to do. I don't know why it's not applying the cppflags; It does compile okay if I run `cc -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` and so on manually.

Comment: Ahhh. That's a pain. I appended them to the CFLAGS and it worked. Rather irritating. I had another FreeBSD 10.1 vm set up (the same way) and it worked on that. I'm not sure what the difference is between them; I'll have to investigate.

Thanks!